# How to scroll to div which was hidden earlier but would be visible on label click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am trying to scroll my webpage to a div which would get visible once I click on a label, it doesn't work.

**jsfiddle** :
Demo.html
    http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/8w8gughf/

I followed a tutorial to animate HTML, Body but it doesn't work somehow. Below is the script and demo html.

```
<script src="http://localhost/app/static/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .addDiv{
    font-size: 20px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:40%;
    border:solid;
    width:16%;
    border-color:#808080;
        }
.addDiv + input{
  display:none;
}
.addDiv + input + *{
 display:none;
 }
.addDiv+ input:checked + *{
 display:block;
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
.inner1 {
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    background:#808080;
    background-color:#808080;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.inner2 {
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    background:green;
    background-color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#button").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#moredetails1").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>

<label class="addDiv" for="_1" id="button">Add more details?</label>
<input id="_1" type="checkbox">

<div class="inner" style="margin-top:20px;" id="moredetails1">
    <div class="inner1">
        <section>
            Enter Name:<input type="text" /><br /><br />
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">
        <section>
            Enter Name:<input type="text" /><br /><br />
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

what am I missing in above jquery?

Comment: Putyour script below your element in HTML markup or use document ready event

Comment: Hi Wolff, I tried putting script on document ready event.. it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited yout css and script

```
jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ArtyukhAlex/63wy2g0r/1/
```

To make your script capture div's top offset you need it to be visible at the moment when animate function executing, so the best solution is to show and hide it with script instead of css.